# PHP Increase value in XML

Tags: php, xml

What im trying to accomplish is to increase create and increase a value in XML.

Code:

```
    // CONNECT TO DATABASE
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    // OPEN XML
    $_xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>\n";
    $_xml .="<ADS>\n";

    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $_xml .=" <AD>\n";
    $_xml .="   <ID><![CDATA[" . $counter . "]]></ID>\n";
    $_xml .="   <TITLE><![CDATA[" . $db_field['title'] . "]]></TITLE>\n";
    $_xml .="   <DESCRIPTION><![CDATA[" . $db_field['description'] . "]]></DESCRIPTION>\n";
    $_xml .="   <EMAIL><![CDATA[" . $db_field['email'] . "]]></EMAIL>\n";
    $_xml .="   <PHONE><![CDATA[" . $db_field['phone'] . "]]></PHONE>\n";
    $_xml .="   <ADDRESS><![CDATA[" . $db_field['address'] . "]]></ADDRESS>\n";
    $_xml .="   <ZIP_CODE><![CDATA[" . $zipcode . "]]></ZIP_CODE>\n";
    $_xml .="   <LOCATION_COUNTRY><![CDATA[" . $country . "]]></LOCATION_COUNTRY>\n";
    $_xml .="   <LOCATION_STATE><![CDATA[" . $state . "]]></LOCATION_STATE>\n";
    $_xml .="   <LOCATION_CITY><![CDATA[" . $city . "]]></LOCATION_CITY>\n";
    $_xml .="   <CATEGORY><![CDATA[" . $db_field['category'] . "]]></CATEGORY>\n";
    $_xml .="   <BEDROOMS>" . $db_field['bedrooms'] . "</BEDROOMS>\n";
    $_xml .="   <BATHROOMS>" . $db_field['bathrooms'] . "</BATHROOMS>\n";
    $_xml .="   <PETS>" . $db_field['pets'] . "</PETS>\n";
    $_xml .="   <BROKERFEE>" . $broker . "</BROKERFEE>\n";
    $_xml .="   <SURFACE>" . $db_field['surface'] . "</SURFACE>\n";
    $_xml .="   <IMAGE_URL><![CDATA[" . $db_field['image_url'] . "]]></IMAGE_URL>\n";
    $_xml .="   <IMAGE_URL><![CDATA[http://www.path to image]]></IMAGE_URL>\n";
    $_xml .="   <PRICE>" . $db_field['price'] . "</PRICE>\n";
    $_xml .="   <CURRENCY>" . $currency . "</CURRENCY>\n";
    $_xml .=" </AD>\n";
    } 

    // CLOSE XML
    $_xml .="</ADS>";

    // ECHO XML DATA
    echo $_xml;
```

I want the "$counter" to provide a value of 1 and for every extra result it should at 1. Not my cup of joe, total noob when it comes to this. I can get a value from the mysql database, but requires that the first item should start with value 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$counter` with `++$counter`.

Comment: Thanks! tried $counter++, will remember to try it the other way around next time.